# Object null at Entity's @Override Equals Method

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, nullpointerexception

I'm currently developing one of my company's project. I use JSF and PrimeFaces. According to the project requirements, I use PrimeFaces SelectOneMenu to show the employee list like the following...

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="employee" value="#{employeeBean.employee}"
converter="employeeConverter">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{employeeBean.employeeList}" var="emp"
    itemLabel="#{emp.name}" itemValue="#{emp}" />
</p>
```

Here is my Employee Object's Equals Method...

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceOf Employee)) {
        return false;
    }
    Employee employee = (Employee) obj;
    return this.id.equals(employee.getId());
}
```

If I create the employee object `Employee employee = new Employee();` at Employee Bean init Method `@PostConstruct public void init(){}`, the employee object represented by `this` becomes null. If I don't create the employee object, everything works fine. Why? I have no idea. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The `this` variable is never `null`, however `this.id` is probably `null` after you construct the instance, but before you assign a value to `id`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line,

```
return this.id.equals(employee.getId());
```

is not null safe. It will still throw NPE when `id` is `null`, which may be the case when you create the entity instance manually using `new` operator without setting any of its properties instead of obtaining an instance from the DB by JPA means. Fix it accordingly:

```
return id != null ? id.equals(employee.id) : employee == this;
```

Note that I also improved the reflexivity of the comparison by adding `employee == this`. See further also the first point of the [contract of `equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean if we create the entity instance manually, it can't accept the instance which comes from DB anymore?

Comment: Oh! I still confuse this step by step procedures. `this` represents the instance comes from DB at this condition?

Comment: The `this` represents the current instance. So, `Employee e = new Employee(); boolean equal = e.equals(e);` returns true this way. Without that, it would return false which is illogical.